# How to send base64 image in attachment of email using base64 link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email-attachments, ftp-server

I have `base64` image url and i want to send this image as email attachment but its not working.Throwing error `PathTooLongException`

My code :

```
   System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Base64urlpath);
   attachment.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
   myMail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Please answer me in `system.web.Mail`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The constructor you are using is not accepting base64 input, but needs a path to a file:

> `public Attachment (string fileName);`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `fileName`
>       String
>
> A String that contains a file path to use to create this attachment.

(quoted from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Mail_Attachment__ctor_System_String_)). And because your encoded image is longer than 260 characters, you get the exception that the path is too long.

It seems like one of the constructors accepting a `Stream` might be what you're looking for.

One possibility to convert your base64 encoded image to a stream is to create a `MemoryStream` out of it:

```
var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64urlpath);
using var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
var attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, null); // you may want to provide a name here
```

Comment: i am getting error  `System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. 
   at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
   at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String`

Comment: I am using this ` string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);`

Comment: If you already have a `Stream` then just use that to create your attachment. No need to make a detour via Base64 encoding.

Comment: Plx updt ur answr,crating MS`FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(stream);
                                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);
                                imgslide.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64," + base64String;
                            }`